# Renumber rows -- sort by score column and change sequence column

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table

[image]

that I want to sort it by 'score' descending and then rename 'num' so that the highest score will be named 001, second highest 002, next one 003 etc...

The result should look like this:

[image]

By now I have sorted it by score DESC, but I don't know how I'd rename num in each row with a different name.
I'd prefer this to be done without procedures or functions.

I'm working in MySQL Workbench and MariaDB

Comment: Add to your question the tag of the specific sql language you're using

Comment: Do I see num as a varchar?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @Ezlo yes, in some cases I will be changing names like this: A_1, A_2, A_3 etc

Comment: I've removed the MySQL tag and added MariaDB.

Comment: With MariaDB 10.2 or MySQL 8.0, use `ROWNUM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT player, 
       score,
       LPAD(@row:=@row+1, 3, '0') AS num
FROM Table1 T,(SELECT @row:=0)R
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

**Demo Link**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/562802/5

**Output**

```
player  score   num
Susu    1105    001
Susu    944     002
Susu    816     003
Susu    760     004
Susu    748     005
Susu    649     006
Susu    549     007
Susu    378     008
Susu    253     009
```

For Updating original table with new `num` you can use `Update Using Join`:

```
UPDATE Table1 T1 JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT player, 
       score,
       LPAD(@row:=@row+1, 3, '0') AS num
FROM Table1 T,(SELECT @row:=0)R
ORDER BY score DESC
)T3)T2  
ON (T1.player=T2.player 
AND T1.score=T2.score)
SET T1.num=T2.num;
```

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ca321/1

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem to correctly name the rows (the highest score is 2 for example)
Also it's important for me to rename the existing column 'num' and have 00 (or some other string) before the actual enumerating

Comment: Edited: I got it to work. Thank you. How would I change the values  in the existing column 'num' tho?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select *, row_number() over (order by score desc) as num
from table t;
```

However, this would produced sequence numbers without padded zero.

Since  *MariaDB* doesn't have a analytical function then you can use :

```
SET @num = 0;

select player, score, @num:= @num+1 AS num
from table t
order by score desc;
```

Comment: MariaDB does support `ROW_NUMBER` as of version 10.2: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/ @Lommmp: Which version of MariaDB are you using? Which of the two queries have you tried?